# Where do javascript script get compiled in my solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've been using BlockUI Jquery script in my solution using the Content Delivery network:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the scenario that happened:
1- I ran my solution once with no internet connection => I got a javascript error that blockUI is not loaded

2- I connected the internet and ran the solution again => it worked fine

3- I disconnected the internet and ran the solution => it worked fine

My question is:

Where did these files get cached ?

EDIT: 
I'm looking for the location of the files that are loaded, as I need to copy these files to another computer that has no internet access.

Comment: What do you mean, compiled? Do you mean cached?

Comment: @TZHX Fixed it, thanks !

Comment: they get cached on your storage medium

Comment: It would be nice of you to share your solution with the community.

Comment: I'm sure it got cached in the browser

Comment: @MorHaviv I don't think this is necessary for the question

Comment: Thanks anyways, I guess I have to do more reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the file from the `src` attribute in the `script` tag and save it where you need it...

Comment: As he said just go to the url http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js with your browser, right click  and choose save as. Then change the reference from "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" to the path in your solution